# EnityManager Injection via HK2 in WebSockets

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager, java-websocket, hk2

I have written 2 WebSocket ServerEndpoints that inject Services that themselves interact with the Database using injected instances of the JPA EntityManager.

The application is a web application deployed on a Tomcat Server, using Jersey as JAX-RS implementation and Hibernate as JPA Provider.

Sometimes it happens that the EntityManager is closed when trying to the DB *inside* the Endpoints. Also I fear I might have produced code that triggers a Memory Leak.

This is the custom `ServerEndpoint.Configurator` that I am using (based on https://gist.github.com/facundofarias/7102f5120944c462a5f77a17f295c4d0):

```
public class Hk2Configurator extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {
    private static ServiceLocator serviceLocator;

    public Hk2Configurator() {
        if (serviceLocator == null) {
            serviceLocator = ServiceLocatorUtilities.createAndPopulateServiceLocator();
            ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(serviceLocator, new ServicesBinder()); // binds the "normal" Services that interact with the DB

            ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(serviceLocator, new AbstractBinder() {
                @Override
                protected void configure() {
                    bindFactory(EntityManagerFactory.class).to(EntityManager.class);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T getEndpointInstance(final Class<T> endpointClass) throws InstantiationException {
        T endpointInstance = super.getEndpointInstance(endpointClass);

        serviceLocator.inject(endpointInstance);

        return endpointInstance;
    }
}
```

In the rest of the application I am using the same `ServicesBinder`, but a different `Binder` for the EntityManager.

The `EntityManagerFactory` looks like this:

```
public class EntityManagerFactory implements Factory<EntityManager> {
    private static final javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory FACTORY = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistenceUnit");

    @Override
    public final EntityManager provide() {
        return FACTORY.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Override
    public final void dispose(final EntityManager instance) {
        instance.close();
    }
}
```

**It is loaded with the Scope `RequestScoped`** (only there, not in the WebSocket Endpoints).

I tried creating an `EntityManager` instance for every access in my DAOs, but then I would run into `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationExceptions` eventually since my DTOs need an open `EntityManager` (implicitly).

Any suggestions on how to circumvent the issues I'm having?

Comment: `bindFactory(EntityManagerFactory.class).to(EntityManager.class);` - try to set the scope explicitly. The default scope is Singeleton for services, not the RequestScope. Also, it is not possible to have several implementations or factories for a service.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to fix my issue by simply rewriting the EntityManager handling to create and close an EntityManager every time I interact with the database.