# Dependency Injection in JavaFX and Jetty with WebSocket

Tags: java, javafx, websocket, jetty-9, hk2

I am working on a JavaFX Application that starts an embedded Jetty server to listen for network requests.  I have a use case where I need to respond to normal HTTP request as well as WebSockets.  As the stage is controlled by these requests, I have a manager class that takes over control of the stage from the base Application class.  To illustrate, here is the Application class:

```
public class ServerApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Log.InitLogger("subject server", Level.ALL);
    DBServer.StartServer();
    final LoginManager manager = new LoginManager(primaryStage);
    final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().register(
            new AbstractBinder() {
                @Override
                protected void configure() {
                    bind(manager).to(SService.class);
                    bind(manager).to(DCS.class);
                }
            });
    Server server = new Server(rc);
    server.start();

    manager.showLoginScreen();
}
}
```

Here's the server class's constructor:

```
   public Server(final ResourceConfig rc) throws ServletException,  DeploymentException, IOException {

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");

    jettyServer = new Server(65534  );
    jettyServer.setHandler(context);
    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(jettyServer);
    ServerContainer serverContainer = WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(context);
    serverContainer.addEndpoint(Socket.class);

    jettyServer.addConnector(connector);

    final ServletHolder jerseyServlet;
    if(rc == null) {
        jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(ServletContainer.class, "/*");
        jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", SUBJECT_REST_PACKAGES);
    }
    else {
        rc.packages(REST_PACKAGES);
        jerseyServlet = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(rc));
        context.addServlet(jerseyServlet, "/*");
    }

    jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

    // Tells the Jersey Servlet which REST service/class to load.


    jmDNS = JmDNS.create(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
    serviceInfo = ServiceInfo.create("_http._tcp.local.", "Service", 65534, "Ready");

}
```

For the classes defined in my REST_PACKAGES, HK2 works successfully and resolves the bindings.  However, I'm running into issues with the websocket class and dependency injection.  I found this post: [EnityManager Injection via HK2 in WebSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666129/enitymanager-injection-via-hk2-in-websockets), which almost works, but when the WebSocket is instantiated, I get an error int that HK2 can't resolve the DCSService class, which is what the socket needs.  So my question is if there is a way to assemble all these technologies, JavaFX, Websockets, Jetty, and HK2 to work together?  I know there may be other ways to achieve this, but things like events and pub/sub models don't seem to fit.  This seems to be a corner case.

Update, as per request, here's the code for the configurator:

public class MyConfigurator extends Configurator {
    private ServiceLocator serviceLocator;

```
public MyConfigurator() {
    serviceLocator = ServiceLocatorUtilities.createAndPopulateServiceLocator();
    ServiceLocatorUtilities.enableImmediateScope(serviceLocator);
    ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(serviceLocator, new AbstractBinder() {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(MySocket.class).to(MySocket.class);
            bind(LManager.class).to(DCService.class);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public <T> T getEndpointInstance(Class<T> endpointClass) {
    return serviceLocator.getService(endpointClass);
}
}
```

Comment: Based on the link you provided, can you verify that the configurator is being used? If it is, can you show your code for it.

Comment: Are you creating more than one ServiceLocator?  It's possible they are not seeing each other's bindings.  Try and use https://javaee.github.io/hk2/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/ServiceLocatorUtilities.html#dumpAllDescriptors-org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator- to get a list of services the locator knows about